# Chrome on iPhone5 open passing target

Tags: google-chrome, iphone-5

I was wondering if anyone knew of any issues in chrome

I have a piece of code that opens a new window in js passing a window name - something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
   var newin = window.open("https://test.com.au/test.asp","windowName","scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,fullscreen=yes,width=800,height=600,top=5,left=5");
 }
</script> 

<a href="javascript:test();"> click me</a>
```

this works on all browsers on my computer and on iPhone safari but on iPhone 5 on google chrome it sends the page into a loop and keeps trying to load it.

the page I am loading requires the window name to be passed

thanks